# Multi-Environment Configs in CraftCMS 3

Tags: craft3, multi-environment

I am at the very early stages of using CractCMS but I'm keen to get off to the correct start, writing notes as I go along etc but I cannot figure this issue out.

I have setup the Multi-Environment Configs to allow me to use, dev, staging and production sites, staging and production appear to work correctly but development site is causing issues.

I know it's something to do with the .env file and

```
ENVIRONMENT="production"
```

If I change that to

```
ENVIRONMENT="dev"
```

The development site will work.

What I can't understand is, both staging and production work so why not development?

I thought by using db.php and general.php I could do away with .env? Other than this line I can.

Here's my General.php code

```
<?php

return [
// Global settings
'*' => [
    // Default Week Start Day (0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday...)
    'defaultWeekStartDay' => 1,

    // Enable CSRF Protection (recommended)
    'enableCsrfProtection' => true,

    // Whether "index.php" should be visible in URLs
    'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,

    // Control Panel trigger word
    'cpTrigger' => 'admin',


    // The secure key Craft will use for hashing and encrypting data
    'securityKey' => '*******************************',
],

// Dev environment settings
'dev' => [

    // Base site URL
    'siteUrl' => null,



    'basePath' => '@webroot/cpresources',

    'baseUrl'  => 'https://mydomain.test',
],

// Staging environment settings
'staging' => [
    // Base site URL
    'siteUrl' => null,

    'basePath' => '@webroot/cpresources',

    'baseUrl'  => 'https://staging.mydomain.co.uk',
],

// Production environment settings
'production' => [
    // Base site URL
    'siteUrl' => null,

    'basePath' => '@webroot/cpresources',

    'baseUrl'  => 'https://mydomain.co.uk',
],
];
```

Here's my db.php code

```
<?php

return array(
'*' => array(
    'tablePrefix' => '',
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'schema' => 'public',
),
'dev' => [
    // Base site URL
    'server' => 'localhost',
    'user' => 'myusername',
    'password' => '*************',
    'database' => 'mydatabasename',
],
'staging' => array(
    'server' => 'localhost',
    'user' => 'myusername',
    'password' => '*************',
    'database' => 'craft_cms_staging',
),
'production' => array(
    'server' => 'localhost',
    'user' => 'myusername',
    'password' => '*',
    'database' => 'craft_cms_production',
),
);
```

Now before anyone says anything about uploading db.php and general.php to git etc because of passwords, I have put both these files in the .gitignore file. I felt this was the best option but if I'm wrong, please explain?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I had set web/index.php to production.

The reason why both staging and production were working was due to me using the same username and password for the database.

Once I had changed this to dev, it now works so I no longer need the .env file.